# Ubuntu won't react after I close the lid

Tags: ideapad, lid

I have Ubuntu-Mate Disco Dingo installed on my IdeaPad which is working perfectly fine, except for one thing. If I close the lid and open it up later I can't click anything anymore. The desktop shows up and anything is where it should be, I can move the mouse around perfectly, but I cannot click on anything nor use any other key. I can't even shut it down properly in this state, just have to hold the power button until it turns off.

Does anyone have a solution for this? It is really annoying that I have to boot down and up again every time I go from one class to another.

Comment: Can you try CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to a full TTY, then CTRL+ALT+F7 to get back to your desktop? Sometimes that will sort it out.